# Is there a way to enforce order of execution of props on a Native Component?

Tags: react-native

I came across a bug in a React Native app that makes use of a native view component, and tracked it down to the order of execution of the property settings methods (e.g. `@ReactProp` methods on Android).

I found that I had to put the prop method that needed setting first as the last prop in the component's JSX declaration, which is a little counter-intuitive.

Is there a way to enforce this order?

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't specifically answer the question, one way around this, when specific props are dependent on each other like this, is to bundle them in an object, which on Android would be passed to the native method via a `ReadableMap`. That way all the dependent data is in one place and can be handled in the correct order.